# Pandas - groupby one column and get mean of all other columns

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe, with columns:

```
cols = ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

If I groupby one column, say, 'A', like so:

```
df.groupby('A')['B'].mean()
```

It works.

---

But I need to groupby one column and then *get the mean of all other columns*. I've tried:

```
df[cols].groupby('A').mean()
```

But I get the error:

```
KeyError: 'A'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I cannot reproduce. I'm guessing the `KeyError` is from `df[cols]`, rather than from `groupby("A")`. Can you double check?

Comment: You don't have the column 'A' in your data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
df.groupby('A').agg('mean')
```

**sample data**

```
   B  C  A
0  1  4  K
1  2  6  S
2  4  7  K
3  6  3  K
4  2  1  S
5  7  3  K
6  8  9  K
7  9  3  K


print(df.groupby('A').agg('mean'))




     B         C
A                    
K  5.833333  4.833333
S  2.000000  3.500000
```

Comment: `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 25, placement implies 1`(there are actually 25 columns)

Comment: Should work. Unless you want something else done. Helpful to give sample datasets

Comment: thanks. but `df[cols].groupby('A').mean()` sholud work too, right?

Comment: absolutely. Its working on my end too. Just prefer shorter code

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df.groupby('col').mean()`. For example to calcualte `mean` for columns `'A'`, `'B'` and `'C'`:

```
   A    B  C  D
0  1  NaN  1  1
1  1  2.0  2  1
2  2  3.0  1  1
3  1  4.0  1  1
4  2  5.0  2  1

df[['A', 'B', 'C']].groupby('A').mean()
```

or

```
df.groupby('A')[['A', 'B', 'C']].mean()
```

Output:

```
     B         C
A
1  3.0  1.333333
2  4.0  1.500000
```

If you need mean for all columns:

```
df.groupby('A').mean()
```

Output:

```
     B         C    D
A
1  3.0  1.333333  1.0
2  4.0  1.500000  1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the missing column is string rather than numeric?

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
  'A': ['big', 'small','small', 'small'],
  'B': [1,0,0,0],
  'C': [1,1,1,0],
  'D': ['1','0','0','0']
})
df.groupby(['A']).mean()
```

Output:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| big | 1.0 | 1.0 |
| small | 0.0 | 0.6666666666666666 |

Here, converting the column to a numeric type such as `int` or `float` produces the desired result:

```py
df.D = df.D.astype(int)
df.groupby(['A']).mean()
```

Output:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| big | 1.0 | 1.0 | 1.0 |
| small | 0.0 | 0.6666666666666666 | 0.0 |